# C++ srand function looping

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, loops, srand

I have the following method as part of a password generating program to generate a random password which is then validated.

My problem is that the srand function never meets the validation requirements and keeps looping back to create a new password.

Im posting the code below to ask if anyone has a more efficient way to create the random password so that it will meet validation requirements instead of looping back continously.Thanks.

```
static bool verifyThat(bool condition, const char* error) {
    if(!condition) printf("%s", error);
    return !condition;
}




//method to generate a random password for user following password guidelines.  
void generatePass()

{
    FILE *fptr;//file pointer
    int iChar,iUpper,iLower,iSymbol,iNumber,iTotal;


    printf("\n\n\t\tGenerate Password selected ");

    get_user_password:
    printf("\n\n\t\tPassword creation in progress... ");

    int i,iResult,iCount;
    char password[10 + 1];
    char strLower[59+1] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTUVWXYZ!£$%^&*";


    srand(time (0));

    for(i = 0; i < 10;i++)
    {
        password[i] = strLower[(rand() % 52)];

    }
    password[i] = '\0';


    iChar = countLetters(password,&iUpper,&iLower,&iSymbol,&iNumber,&iTotal);

    //folowing statements used to validate password
    iChar = countLetters(password,&iUpper,&iLower,&iSymbol,&iNumber,&iTotal);
    iUpper = countLetters(password,&iUpper,&iLower,&iSymbol,&iNumber,&iTotal);
    iLower =countLetters(password,&iUpper,&iLower,&iSymbol,&iNumber,&iTotal);
    iSymbol =countLetters(password,&iUpper,&iLower,&iSymbol,&iNumber,&iTotal);
    iNumber = countLetters(password,&iUpper,&iLower,&iSymbol,&iNumber,&iTotal);
    iTotal = countLetters(password,&iUpper,&iLower,&iSymbol,&iNumber,&iTotal);



    if(verifyThat(iUpper >= 2, "Not enough uppercase letters!!!\n")
     || verifyThat(iLower >= 2, "Not enough lowercase letters!!!\n")
     || verifyThat(iSymbol >= 1, "Not enough symbols!!!\n")
     || verifyThat(iNumber >= 2, "Not enough numbers!!!\n")
     || verifyThat(iTotal >= 9, "Not enough characters!!!\n")
     || verifyThat(iTotal <= 15, "Too many characters!!!\n"))

    goto get_user_password;

    iResult = checkWordInFile("dictionary.txt", password);

    if(verifyThat(iResult != gC_FOUND, "Password contains small common 3 letter word/s."))
    goto get_user_password;

    iResult = checkWordInFile("passHistory.txt",password);

    if(verifyThat(iResult != gC_FOUND, "Password contains previously used password."))
    goto get_user_password;


    printf("\n\n\n Your new password is verified ");
    printf(password);

    //writing password to passHistroy file.


    fptr = fopen("passHistory.txt", "w");   // create or open the file
    for( iCount = 0; iCount < 8; iCount++)
    {
        fprintf(fptr, "%s\n", password[iCount]);
    }

    fclose(fptr);


    printf("\n\n\n");
    system("pause");



}//end of generatePass method.
```

Comment: Just an idea: Use the ascii value of characters instead of a huge array... `static_cast<char>(rand() % 26 + 'A')` for instance will get you an upper case alphabetic.

Comment: Hi,yes im calling this validaton from a seperate method that counts by using the ASCII table.

Comment: Hey Anthony Sottile,how would I implement this in my code?Would this mean discarding the array and using this code snippet,if so could you show how it would be incorporated into the code,Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at your code at glance and I think I have found the reasons inspite of which  validation requirements aren`t meet.

I suggest you to pay attention to the following parts of your code:
1) `char strLower[59+1] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTUVWXYZ!£$%^&*";`

here you should **add numbers 0..9**, this is one of the reasons why requirements could not be met, because *how number can be picked if it isn`t in the set of numbers from which you pick?!*
replace it for ex. with:

```
char strLower[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTUVWXYZ!£$%^&*0123456789";
```

2) `password[i] = strLower[(rand() % 52)];` - and in this part of the code, **replace** `52` **with total number of symbols in string** from which you randomly pick numbers.
I recommend you to replace it with the following code:

```
password[i] = strLower[(rand() % (sizeof(strLower) / sizeof(char) - 1))];
```

Answer (score 1):

you could alter your algorithm.

- choose at random a number of Upper characeters that is above 2.
- choose at random a number of Lower character that is above 2.
- choose at random a number of Sybmol character that is above 1.
- choose at random a number of Number characters that is above 2.

and then recompose your password with the random items, re-ordered at random. Fill with whatever character you want to pas the verifyThat predicates: >=9 and <= 15.

And please: don't use goto. Make function calls instead.

Comment: I use a method also in this program that counts number of ASCII charaters in password for validation.Im just not sure what you mean in ths answer.Do you mean make a random string from upper,lower,symbol,char and concatonate them.Could you show this concept implemented in code? Cheers Brian.